# Laravel 5 array: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to take items from my database and put them into the format required by the "laravel-paypal" package:

```
$data['items'] = [
    [
        'name' => 'Product 1',
        'price' => 9.99,
        'desc'  => 'Description for product 1'
        'qty' => 1
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Product 2',
        'price' => 4.99,
        'desc'  => 'Description for product 2',
        'qty' => 2
    ]
];
```

So I have a sweet query:

```
$order_items = DB::table('order_items')
                        ->where('order_id', $order['id'])
                        ->join('products', 'order_items.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                        ->selectRaw('products.name, order_items.price + order_items.tax as price, order_items.quantity as qty')
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
```

Which yields:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#296 ▼
    +"name": "fugit"
    +"price": 727.82
    +"qty": 1
  }
  1 => {#298 ▼
    +"name": "MEMBERSHIP"
    +"price": 35.0
    +"qty": 1
  }
]
```

But when I try to put it into the required array:

```
$data = [];
$data['items'] = $order_items;
```

I get the error message:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

With details of:

```
 protected function setCartItems($items)
    {
        return (new Collection($items))->map(function ($item, $num) {
            return [
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$num  => $item['name'],
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$num   => $item['price'],
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'.$num  => isset($item['desc']) ? $item['desc'] : null,
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$num   => isset($item['qty']) ? $item['qty'] : 1,
            ];
        })->flatMap(function ($value) {
            return $value;
        });
```

I've read all the solutions for this error message, and they all say that what I have is an array of objects, not an array of arrays, which is why I'm getting this message. I get it. They all say that I have to access the data with `$order_items->price`. I get it.

But I need the data in that array of arrays format and since it's a nested array, I can't even figure out how I would do it with a foreach loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just write `$item = json_decode(json_encode($item),true);` before `return [` for solving it for now. If you want to opt for a more greater solution read about Objects and array :)

Comment: Simply use `$item->name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Type Casting object to an array like this for exemple :

```
 protected function setCartItems($items)
{
    return (new Collection($items))->map(function ($item, $num) {
        $itemArray = (array) $item;
        return [
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$num  => $itemArray ['name'],
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$num   => $itemArray ['price'],
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'.$num  => isset($itemArray ['desc']) ? $itemArray ['desc'] : null,
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$num   => isset($itemArray ['qty']) ? $itemArray ['qty'] : 1,
        ];
    })->flatMap(function ($value) {
        return $value;
    });
```